# Restrict languages auto-detected by VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently, when I paste JSON into a new tab in VSCode, it will usually detect its Language Mode as something else (ex CoffeeScript, etc, etc). Usually these are languages that I never use and don't care about.

Can I restrict the list of possible languages that it auto-identifies, so that it has a better chance of realizing that what I pasted in was JSON?

Comment: why do you work with untitled files or txt files with structure, if you give the file a proper extension no language detection is needed

Comment: @rioV8 Maybe I don't want to save it? There are many ways in which I can tell VSCode what the content is, but here my question is about saving time and having it get auto-detected correctly.

Comment: auto detection depends on the files you have opened in this session with a known language ID

Comment: No that's not correct. If open a new tab and paste in some code (or in my case, JSON) it will attempt to detect the Language Mode based on the pasted content.

Comment: they have told me that when I created an issue related to language detection, I they did not had plans to change it

Comment: Regardless of what they told you, you can try it yourself and see that VSCode attempts to detect the language based on the content pasted into a new tab (with no file associated with it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of that setting, `Workbench > Editor: Language Detection`, says that it can be **scoped** to restrict which languages it is applied to:

> // Controls whether the language in a text editor is automatically
> detected unless the language has been explicitly set by the language
> picker. This can also be scoped by language so you can specify which
> languages you do not want to be switched off of. This is useful for
> languages like Markdown that often contain other languages that might
> trick language detection into thinking it's the embedded language and
> not Markdown.

So you could try this setting (in your `settings.json`):

```
"[json, jsonc]": {
  "workbench.editor.languageDetection": false
}
```

This may only apply to previously set `json` files so let me know if this makes any difference.  I don't think there is any other option other than disabling all language detection - of which I assume you are aware.

Comment: Thank you for this! I set the default language via:
  ```"files.defaultLanguage": "json"```
And then turned off language detection scoped for JSON as you suggested. That does the trick!